not bumping version correctly using gitversion
I am using gitversion in azure devops. But it is not calculating the version correctly. As I am implementing it in existing repo, which has a lot of history with something like release-03082024 in branch name and it uses it's base for calculation.
I do not want it, so tried ignoring it by applying ignore in configuration yaml based on date. Then explicitly set v1.0.0. If I take a look at log it considers it as base. But even command is to bump patch it keep bumping major.
Here is the complete log and my configuration. I post in gitversion forum but didn't get a solution, so posting it here hoping that someone can help me.
configuration
mode: Mainline
major-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(breaking|major)'
minor-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(feature|minor)'
patch-version-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(fix|patch)'
no-bump-message: '\+semver:\s?(none|skip)'
commit-message-incrementing: Enabled
ignore:
  commits-before: 2024-03-09T06:00:00
branches:
  develop:
    regex: ^vertest$  # Matches your developement branch
    tag: ''  # No tag associated with the feature branch
    source-branches: []

Note --> It show redline to Mainline mode I am testing it with gitversion 5.11.1 and 5.12
I expect it should bump to 1.0.1 but it bumping 2.0.0

Hi there, Can you please share further details on how you observed the GitVersion was unexpected? Was it generated in your pipeline by GitTools - Visual Studio Marketplace? Please also share a pipeline YAML definition or your detailed steps/screenshots to help understand how the issue was reproduced. Thx.

How did you "explicitly set v1.0.0"?
